# Calculating divergence and flux of geodesic word lines

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, vector-fields, geodesics

Given a family of neighbouring geodesic word lines, is there a way of calculating properties such as their divergence or flux? maybe by converting the tangent vectors of the world lines to a vector field?
This is something I thought about when seeing an image of simulated photon orbits around a black hole:

[image]

In this case, how would one go about calculating the divergence or flux of photon orbits around a black hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical construct that you are looking for is called a [(geodesic) congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)). A geodesic congruence is a family of non-intersecting geodesics that completely cover some part of your spacetime. Geodesic congruences play an important role in the analysis of general relativity.

Since in each point in your spacetime region there is exactly one geodesic from the congruence passing through that point, we can construct a vector field $X^\mu$ by assigning to each point the tangent vector of the geodesic passing through that point. Conversely, you can recover the congruence by finding the integral curves of $X^\mu$.

The fact that the members of the congruence are geodesics is reflect in the vector field $X^\mu$ by the property

$$ X^\alpha \nabla_\alpha X^\mu = 0$$.